# Noise estimation from a given trajectory (Matlab)

Tags: signal-processing, noise

With a given trajectory (or signal) from a measurement,
how can one give an estimation from the noise amplitude? considering that it is a random gaussian noise.

I given here an example of two trajectories, before and after smoothing.

What I would like to find is an estimation of the amplitude of a random gaussian noise.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A gaussian noise doesn't have a fixed amplitude and its values are just defined by a gaussian probability function so they can go to infinity.
If you're looking for the standard deviation of the noise a given point P, you can sample a few points around it, subtract the smoothed curve from them, and compute their [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Population_standard_deviation_of_grades_of_eight_students).

Note : the standard deviation is actually the average amplitude.